# Global minimum of convex function over nonconvex set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable continuously function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $g$ is strictly convex in non-convex OPEN set $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to ask whether local minimum of $g$ in $D$ must be global  in $D$.

Namely, suppose $u\in D$ is local minimum of $g$, does
$ g(u)\le g(x) $
for all $x\in D$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No. A simple counter example: $$f(x)=x^2 \\ D = \{-3\leq x\leq -2, 1\leq x\leq 2\}$$
Then $x=-2$ is a local minimum, but $x=1$ is the global minimum.

Comment: What about open set $D$. Does it hold true when $D$ is open set?

Comment: I think in that case it will hold, since optimizing over an open set is equivalent to unconstrained optimization. Think of the example I gave above - over the same set $D$, only open, the set of local minimum points is empty. Then every local minimum is a global minimum (it holds trivially as both sets - local and global min points - are empty). In the case the a local minimum is attained in the interior of the set then since you have a convex function it's also a global minimum.